# JS not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am familiar with the Turbolinks issue, but it seems my fix is not working.

I have this:

```
var ready = function () {
  $('.add_to_cart').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pid = $(this).attr('data-pid');
    $.post('/cart/'+ pid, function(data){
      var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      $('#items-in-cart').text(data['cart_size']);
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

My javascript won't trigger on document load. I have to refresh. I have done this fix on other pages, and it worked. What else should I try / look for?

EDIT:

I am using jquery (through the jquery-rails gem, 3.1.2)

I found this error in jquery:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
                            .apply( matched.elem, args );
```

Found a reference to this 'bug' [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14092).

Edit 2:

Here is my html.slim:

```
=link_to "Add to Cart", "#", class: 'add_to_cart', data: {pid: @product.id}
```

If I get rid of that line, the rest of my javascript functions work in the ready block on page load. If I keep it, I get the Uncaught TypeError.

Edit 3:

I removed turbolinks from my app and it works fine. I'd like to keep turbolinks, but at this point it's my only solution.

Comment: is `'.add_to_cart'` element present on page load? Or does it appear dynamically after the page load based on some request?

Comment: I believe it's present on page:load. I can add an alert function in the same ready function to further test.

Comment: And what about $? Is that jQuery? Is present on the page? Has no javascript errors?

Comment: @Jeff, why don't you refactor your code like in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g0k3m9e7/. It may solve all the problems.

Comment: @KULKING, I could, but would that even be helpful? JSFiddle won't have my enviroment in rails.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that would be helpful. Copy and paste the JS code to your environment and let me know the results after trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the click event since the content is loading via ajax, do this

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(e){
  // js code
});
```